# How do I detect and remove multiple substrings, which may vary?

Tags: python, string, substring

Every week, my school makes us type which assignments we will be doing for the week. I want to do this automatically with python.

Below is a example of what an input I might want the program to take.

```
Unit 1 presentation - Due in 2 days - 40 minutes spent
English Unit 2 Test - Due in 3 days - 1 hour spent
History Essay       - Due in 7 days - 10 minutes spent
```

I want to get rid of everything other than the name of the assigments. How can I achieve this? I can't simply use the find() method since the substrings may vary.

Google hasn't been much help. I'm a beginner, so please bear with me.

Comment: have you heard of "Regex"? Might be what you want. Unless you want something way simpler, then consider the other comments

Comment: In your own words, what is the logic one might use to decide where the assignment name ends, and the unwanted fluff begins? Why do you think you can't use `find()` -- what are you trying to find? You _could_ use regex, but it is probably way overkill here

Comment: Cut what starts in" - Due in ".

Comment: When is your homework due ?

Comment: Split the string by "-" and take the first item of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to take each line as `line` and process as

```
assignment_name = line.split("-")[0].strip()
```